# So I have angular from bower, now what?

Tags: json, angularjs, module, bower, ngresource

I just started a new project, these are the exact steps I have taken.

1. foundation new project_name --libsass
2. bower install angular --dev
3. grunt build

All good, the sass files are compiling, angular is setup under bower_components inside the angular folder, but wait.....

Now I need to add Angular's ng-resource module. I figure I can do a few things here. Let's forget that there is anything better than ngResource (like Restangular) and assume that I may want to install ngResource or any other angular module.

Do I need to add them each individually from bower, because I can't find a bower package for ngResource like I could angular. Or can I just throw the angular modules inside the `/bower_components/angular` folder and update the bower.json with the dependency for that module?

Is that the right way?

If so, how would my dependency section of the `/bower_components/angular/bower.json` look like?

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "main": "./angular.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    //what goes here?
  }
}
```

also do I just manually add the modules in and update the bower.json or is there some other better way of doing this?

I'm sorry I am new to bower and it seems very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to do it! You could make use of  `--save` option of bower to have the dependencies.

For example you could have done:

```
bower install angular --dev --save
```

So that, the bower.json file is automatically updated by the bower and you don't have to touch it!

Quoting from the docs, here are the options that you can use:

> -S, --save: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json dependencies
>
> -D, --save-dev: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json devDependencies

Comment: How can I fix that? Can i just run that command again? Sorry total noob here.

Comment: yup sure.. you can run it again and the bower.json file should be updated.

Comment: so once I do that, just run `bower install ng-resource --dev --save` ? and if I do that will it nest it under the angular dependency? My question is more about how the modules get saved. Are they siblings in the dependency chain or children? Or is that stupid for me to ask?

Comment: you will need to run `bower install ng-resource --save` to make sure ng-resource is listed as a dependency. by just `bower install ng-resource` it will be installed but not added to dependency list in your bower.json file

Comment: so one more question.. why not `bower install ng-resource --dev --save`

Comment: ya sure.. it depends on your requirements.. you can `bower install ng-resource --dev --save`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80239/discussion-between-eric-b-and-abdel-raoof).

Comment: You also might not want to use --dev as you will be using it in the production build